# How to load tflite weights in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm working with neuronal networks and I need to use a Raspberry Pi v2.

When I want to install tensorflow 2.X it fails, and I just can install tensorflow 1.14. For this reason I found the `tflite` library, that theoretically helps me, with a lite version of tf.

Here an image that shows I can't install it.

[image]

First of all, I convert my keras model (model.h5) into `.tflite` model.

```
# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Since here, all OK. The problem is when I want to use this model. With tensorflow I know how to do it,

```
from tensorflow import keras

def importModel(myPath):
    file = open(myPath+'model/model.json', 'r')
    model_json = file.read(); file.close()

    model = keras.models.model_from_json(model_json)
    model.load_weights(myPath+'model/model.h5')

    return model, scaler
```

But I really don't understand how to do it with `tflite`, can somebody help me, please??

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the official [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load the TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="converted_model.tflite")
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# Test the model on random input data.
input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']
input_data = np.array(np.random.random_sample(input_shape), dtype=np.float32)
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

interpreter.invoke()

# The function `get_tensor()` returns a copy of the tensor data.
# Use `tensor()` in order to get a pointer to the tensor.
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

And if you have trouble to install TensorFlow 2.x on your raspberry it's maybe because you are not using the latest version of Python3

Comment: I edited my question. I'm using python3.7.3 but it says there no tf2.X versions...

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/python?hl=en)

Comment: Oh I just found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) that you need to have Raspbian 9.0 or later. You can try both links